# Grouping parameter pack arguments into an initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to figure out how to take a flat parameter pack and convert it into an `initializer_list` where the pack arguments are logically grouped. So let's say I have something like:

```
void doSomething(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char *, int>> args) {
    ...
}
```

I want to write a variadic version of this that takes the pairs as a flat list of arguments. Something like:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void doSomethingFlattened(const char *name, int value, Args... args) {
    doSomething({/*what goes here?*/});
}

doSomethingFlattened("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3);
doSomethingFlattened("a", 1, "b", 2, "c"); // compile error
```

Is this possible in C++17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
void doSomething(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char *, int>> list)
{
    for (auto [a,b] : list)
        std::cout << a << ':' << b << '\n';
}

template <std::size_t ...I, typename ...Args>
void doSomethingFlattened_low(std::index_sequence<I...>, const Args &... args)
{
    auto t = std::tie(args...);
    doSomething({{std::get<I*2>(t), std::get<I*2+1>(t)}...});
}

template <typename ...Args>
void doSomethingFlattened(const Args &... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0, "Expected even number of arguments.");
    doSomethingFlattened_low(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) / 2>{}, args...);
}
```

<kbd>[(run on gcc.godbolt.org)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:18),source:'%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%23include+%3Cinitializer_list%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Avoid+doSomething(std::initializer_list%3Cstd::pair%3Cconst+char+*,+int%3E%3E+list)%0A%7B%0A++++for+(auto+%5Ba,b%5D+:+list)%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+a+%3C%3C+!':!'+%3C%3C+b+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cstd::size_t+...I,+typename+...Args%3E%0Avoid+doSomethingFlattened_low(std::index_sequence%3CI...%3E,+const+Args+%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++auto+t+%3D+std::tie(args...)%3B%0A++++doSomething(%7B%7Bstd::get%3CI*2%3E(t),+std::get%3CI*2%2B1%3E(t)%7D...%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+...Args%3E%0Avoid+doSomethingFlattened(const+Args+%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++static_assert(sizeof...(Args)+%25+2+%3D%3D+0,+%22Expected+even+number+of+arguments.%22)%3B%0A++++doSomethingFlattened_low(std::make_index_sequence%3Csizeof...(Args)+/+2%3E%7B%7D,+args...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++doSomethingFlattened(%22a%22,+1,+%22b%22,+2,+%22c%22,+3)%3B%0A++++//doSomethingFlattened(%22a%22,+1,+%22b%22,+2,+%22c%22)%3B+//+compile+error%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.86567164179105,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:'610')),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.236318407960198,l:'4',m:47.10467706013363,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:9,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+9.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:52.89532293986636,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.13432835820896,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)</kbd>

Comment: @Vitali Yep. It doesn't really matter for your types.

Comment: Yeah I know that. The types were just placeholders but it's pretty straightforward to fix (`std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` instead of `std::tie`).

Answer (score 1):

You might do

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
void doSomethingFlattenedImpl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const Tuple& t) {
    doSomething({std::make_pair(std::get<2 * Is>(t), std::get<2 * Is + 1>(t))...});
}

template <typename ... Args>
void doSomethingFlattened(Args... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0);
    doSomethingFlattenedImpl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) / 2>{},
                             std::make_tuple(args...));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61b99e5875f5a43d)